# Linux: contents of /home/<user>/ replaced and command prompt changed to -bash-4.1$

Tags: unix

I hope I'm providing enough context information below, as the problem I ran into is already vague enough.

Without being aware of it, I managed to replace the contents of my /home/ with something from another folder (the script I was trying to run doesn't do anything even remotely in that direction). 
Also, after this, the command prompt changed to `-bash-4.1$` (before, it was just the regular `<username>@<machinename>` ). Suspecting that this might have something to do with the problem, I found some posts on (changing) the PS1 variable. But that isn't really my concern here. Just want to know what happened, and how I can get back my files.

output of `uname -a`:

```
`Linux xxxxx.xxxxx.com 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
```

Below is a copy-paste of what I did. The first `ls` is done in the same folder as the last `ls`, but as you can see, by just running this python script, the content changed. I'm really lost here.
I realise this is a very vague issue, but any hints/tips on finding out the problem and fixing it would be much appreciated!
(if more specific info is needed, please let me know)

```
`[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx ~]$ ls
Desktop    Downloads  Music       nltk_data  playground  repositories  Videos
Documents  moses.ini  nltk-3.0.0  Pictures   Public      Templates
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx ~]$ ./repositories/scrinfor/analyseMTsegments.pyTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./repositories/scrinfor/analyseMTsegments.py", line 8, in <module>
    import nltk
ImportError: No module named 'nltk'
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx ~]$ cd nltk-3.0.0/
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx nltk-3.0.0]$ ./repositories/scrinfor/analyseMTsegments.py
-bash: ./repositories/scrinfor/analyseMTsegments.py: No such file or directory
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx nltk-3.0.0]$ ../repositories/scrinfor/analyseMTsegments.py
-bash: ../repositories/scrinfor/analyseMTsegments.py: No such file or directory
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx nltk-3.0.0]$ ../repositories
-bash: ../repositories: No such file or directory
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx nltk-3.0.0]$ ls ../repositoreis
ls: cannot access ../repositoreis: No such file or directory
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx nltk-3.0.0]$ ls ../repositories
ls: cannot access ../repositories: No such file or directory
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx nltk-3.0.0]$ cd ..
[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx ~]$ ls
analyseMTsegments.py                 __pycache__`
```

Comment: I don't see how any of those commands could have caused this issue, though it would be nice to see the contents of the Python script just to be sure.  Were any other processes running concurrently with your terminal session?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not aware of any other processes running at the same time. And since these are the first lines of my python script:

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import re
import string
from collections import defaultdict
from optparse import OptionParser
import os
import nltk`

I would think the script doesn't really do anything (seeing that it crashed on ImportError).(sorry for the messed up indentation. Should obviously be one import statement per line)

Comment: You didn't have any files with names like `sys.py` or `re.py` in the same directory as the Python script, right?

Comment: Nope, but those are just Python modules that I downloaded through pip that and could succesfully be imported. (the reason nltk could is because I downloaded the python2(.7 I think) version before, and now needed it for a Python3 script as well.).